# Not able to login in django , while using django-registration 

Tags: django

I had removed email activation as it was an off-line app . Had provided with user-registration . User gets registered . Shows up in the database . But when I try to login , it never logs me in , and shows up an error saying The username and password you gave didn't match . Though I am very sure , that I am entering the right username and password . What can be the error ?

Comment: can you provide the authentication segment of your code?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/django-registration/ I am using this

Comment: Can you see your user in django admin?

Comment: Yup it does show up in django admin . Shows up in the db too .

Answer (score 1):

If you user is not activated you can't login with it. The [Django docs about authentification](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/) are very clear about that. To make the activation happening after a user registered (but without the activation mail) you can use signals. `django-registration` provides a `user_registered` signal for that purpose (`from registration.signals import user_registered`). To find out how to use signals check out the [Django docs about signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/).

Comment: new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
                                   password=self.cleaned_data['password1'],
                                   email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
                                   profile_callback=profile_callback,
                                   send_email = False)
        RegistrationProfile.objects.activate_user(new_user.activation_key)

Comment: I have that in my form . Isn't that enough to activate the user ?

Comment: Hm, yes. That actually should be enough. Can you check if the `is_active` flag is really set to `True` for this user. It should be shown in the admin or you can use `manage.py shell` for it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know. But I can guess the following:

The email_activation marked the user as `active`, and only activated users are able to login. You must be able to mark the user as active immediately after the signup, if you want to skip the email verification.

Comment: new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username=self.cleaned_data['username'],
                                   password=self.cleaned_data['password1'],
                                   email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
                                   profile_callback=profile_callback,
                                   send_email = False)
        RegistrationProfile.objects.activate_user(new_user.activation_key)

Comment: I am doing that to register the user in the forms.py itself .